SQL Server Availability group not working without NTLM
I have disabled NTLM authentication on MS SQL servers by using domain policies to use Kerberos only.
"Network security: Restrict NTLM: Incoming NTLM traffic" set to "Deny all accounts"
"Network security: Restrict NTLM: Outgoing NTLM traffic to remote servers" set to "Deny all"`
And got a non-functional Availability Group with an error in the logs:

Database Mirroring login attempt failed with error: 'Connection handshake failed. An OS call failed: (80090302) 0x80090302(The function requested is not supported). State 66.'.

Domain controllers - Windows server 2019.
SQL Server 2022 CU14.
SQL Server Operating System - Windows Server 2019.
The SPN settings are correct, but it is still now working. Tried to reboot, but it didn't help. And inspect SPN settings also. But it's still not working.
How to turn off NTLM auth and force to use ONLY Kerberos?

Have you looked at this?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/prereqs-restrictions-recommendations-always-on-availability?view=sql-server-ver16#PrerequisitesSI

Is SQL Server configured to run using a domain account?

I found what the problem was. Of course I had SPNs for servers FQND and port 1433. But the endpoins on the nodes were running on port 5022, and I didn't have SPNs for them. As soon as I did this, the Availability Group immediately worked correctly.
So, my problem was solved.

Are the primary and secondary nodes under the same windows domain name ?
Can you check in the alert log when the last startup occured if you can see an error related to SPN registration ?
When registering the SPN, you must use the service account of the server instance that hosts the availability replica. For the SPN to work on all replicas, the same service account must be used for all instances in the WSFC cluster that hosts the availability group.

Yes booth nodes use same service accounts and placed in the same domain. All SPN's are present with server FQDNs. But you gave me an idea. I'm gonna go check it out))))
